# Как получить в List<string> название колонок из dataGridView?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

Такая задача: при клике на колонку в dataGridView ее заголовок (например Column1 и т.д.) должен помещаться в List.

Дайте плиз подсказку, как это сделать, что нужно реализовать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Очень просто, нужно всего лишь обработать событие щелчка мыши по заголовку столбца. Ну и, соответственно, в нем добавить название столбца, по которому кликнули, в `listBox`.

```
private void dataGridView1_ColumnHeaderMouseClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
    {
        listBox1.Items.Add(dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].HeaderText);
    }
```